# Moving a Crossbar in a barn style shed

Tags: framing, construction, shed, engineering

I have a 12x20 workshop and it was shipped with this Crossbar that is in a very inconvenient spot.

```
+-----------------------+
!   !            !      !
!   !            !      !
! Loft.         Crossbar! 12ft
!   !            !      !
!   !            !      !
+-------20ft------door--+
```

I need it to be 2 rafters to the right.

If I build a brand new DOUBLE Crossbar 2 rafters to the right will it be ok to remove the other one?

What else can I do to make it stronger?  I'm installing drywall and insulation on the ceiling and I'm a bit nervous frankly.

[image: shed roof]

Edit:  Should this be the blocking pattern?

[image: Proposed Blocking]

Comment: If it was manufactured you should ask the manufacturer. They might pay it safe and tell you not to touch anything, so hopefully you get answers here too.  But ask them!

Comment: If this roof design came out of a book consult the book for options,  if it came from an engineer, you'll need to find an engineer (this is also an option if it came out of a book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move it, but also install a second one in the other direction. These are "collar ties" (a variant of a "rafter tie"), and their primary purpose is to prevent spreading of the walls and roof due to load and settling. The front beam of the loft storage area is also a rafter tie, and you don't want to leave too long of a span between it and this tie. Right now you have no more than 8 feet unsupported, so strive to maintain that.

You could put the one near the loft up a bit higher, say at the rafter joint, if it's in conjunction with a lower one in the new location. I have confidence that the two together would maintain the integrity of the roof.

Incidentally, the block we see *under* the tie does nothing. It's maybe there in case you decide to install a pullup bar in your shed, as a liability protection for the manufacturer. Also, you don't need to double the tie. They're in tension, so adding more lumber does nothing. Just fasten them well, with say four 3" screws at each junction.

You could also run two boards from the rafter bottom at the wall plate to the center of the level top rafter chord at the existing location to gain headroom. If you fasten them well, say with lag screws, they'll do the same job as the level tie.

Another option would be to install plywood gussets on all the rafter joints. This would make them into single rigid structures, eliminating the need for ties altogether. Triangles with a center depth of say 12" and a length of about 32", screwed and glued well, would easily carry the roof of this small shed.

Related questions:

- [Can I remove a rafter tie from my shed roof framing for better access?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/241910/35141)
- [How should I fasten my shed rafters together at the peak?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/219200/35141) ([photos](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/219247/35141) of the gusset design I mentioned)

Comment: Thank you so much!  What did you mean by the two boards idea? Like make a big triangle across the roof?  Also with the gussets can I use 2x4s in addition to plywood to have something to mount the ceiling to?  I'm leaning towards tongue and groove pine. Also is it just the top that needs gussets or do the middle joints in the rafters need them too?

Comment: Yeah, a big triangle. Sure, you can add whatever blocking you need for a ceiling. If you do it right you could use _just_ blocking.

Comment: I would really like to just do it with blocking and leave the main area open after drywall if that is possible.  How about the picture I posted with 2x4 blocks in green?

Comment: Blocks at those locations would do nothing like what the collar tie does. I'm confused about your thinking with that and concerned that you don't have a grasp of the potential movement in your roof.

Comment: I don't have any idea that's why I was asking.  I saw you mentioned the whole thing could be done with blocking.  I'm guessing you meant the gussets?  Either way after thinking on it all weekend I'm playing it safe and putting up a pair of 2x6s just below the lower rafter joints they will be 2 rafters apart.  I already added my second loft near the right side of the shed for more support.  Now there won't even be more than 4 foot of space without a rafter tie.

Comment: I did not use the word except in reference to the extraneous block in your shed. Maybe read again, more carefully.